# error on mui NativeSelect/NativeSelectInput.js

Tags: material-ui, react-proptypes

Edit: solved with npm install @mui/material surprsingly, installing it with yarn didnt work –

Good day
ive upgrade mui lib
and getting on error on running nextJs server:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isRequired')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/material/node/NativeSelect/NativeSelectInput.js:196:49)
```

these are my mui versions:

```
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.11",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.166",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.11",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.19.6",
    "@mui/x-data-grid-pro": "^6.19.6",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.19.6",
    "@mui/x-license-pro": "^6.10.2",
    "@mui/x-tree-view": "^6.17.0",
```

1. ive looked at other posts on it and tried to install prop-types.
2. tried clearing npm & yarn caches
3. i saw post on manually editing the file that needs isRequired , but cant its a node module:
   @mui/material/node/NativeSelectInput

thanks in advance for your time

Comment: ok solved with npm install @mui/material
surprsingly, installing it with yarn didnt work